# What do you do with photos after scanning them?

Tags: united-states, photo

I've acquired four trunks filled with old pictures, some in frames, some loose, that I'm planning on scanning into my genealogy program.  What does one do with them after scanning?  Surely you wouldn't toss them.  Donate them somewhere?  Pawn them off to another relative?  Keep them around forever?  I'm not sure I want to keep four trunks filled with old pictures around.  Has anyone dealt with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I am one of those nutty people who would happily keep trunks full of old pictures around, but I understand that it's not everyone's cup of tea.

Have you tried contacting other relatives to see if anyone is interested in the photos?

Do you have children who might be interested in them one day?

If not, and you would still like to offload them, try checking with local libraries, archives, museums, and genealogical societies.  They may be willing to accept donations.  I would suggest identifying individuals and carefully labeling the reverse sides of the photos, if possible.

Comment: @Katherine:  I'm afraid I have no children, other than the four-footed variety.  Actually, I acquired the trunks from one of my wife's grownup kids because she didn't want to deal with them anymore (they are four trunks filled, after all!). I had considered the options you suggested, but have not yet come to a decision, other than not willing to just toss them.  Thanks for the validation!